# Pass Generic Object type in a class

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

I already asked this and it was a messed up description so:

I have a class

```
private Class MyClass<T extends SomeClass> //where  SomeClass is an abstract class
{
    SomeClass T=new SomeClass(); //Something like that but which works
}
```

I want to somehow instantiate T or call a method of it perhaps using casting since  SomeClass is abstract and the above is invalid

Comment: You can't instantiate an abstract class.  If you are trying to instantiate a concrete implementation, then you need to figure out which concrete implementation you are trying to instantiate.

Comment: they had public class Abc<T> and I have a similar but <T extends .. >

Comment: I am trying to make this generic. All I need is to access a method that is implemented in the abstract class. Thats all I want

Answer (score 0):

First of all, correct class definition is

```
public class MyClass<T extends SomeClass> { }
```

or

```
private class MyClass<T extends SomeClass> { }
```

if this class is an inner class. 
T will be replaced with some type. It means that

```
SomeClass T =new SomeClass(); // this T is not the T from class definition
```

In the line above you are trying to create an instance of abstract class - it's impossible !

Create class which extends `SomeClass` and implements abstract methods if any and then you can create an instance `SomeClass sc = new MyNewClassWhichExtendsSomeClass()`

Answer (score 0):

The [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) has a pretty good solution to this

```
/**
 * Generic version of the Box class.
 * @param <T> the type of the value being boxed
 */
public class Box<T> {
    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

Just make a method that sets an instance

```
private class MyClass<T extends SomeClass> { 
     private T t;
     public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
     //or
     public MyClass(T t){
         this.t = t;
     }
     public void seriousBusiness(){
         SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) t;
         someClass.someClassMethod();
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited wrong answer away, `new T()` doesn't work.

If you want to get access to methods in an abstract class, they have to be static like:

```
public static int getNumber() {
    return 1;
}
```

You can then access it by:

```
SomeClass.getNumber();
```

Note that SomeClass is not a variable name, but the name of the class!

Comment: SomeClass is an abstract class. All I need is access to one of its methods if I can't instantiate it

Comment: @user3270982 In Java 8, you can do this: SomeClass::someMethod.